# How to refresh as well as savstate of datatable when status is updated in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

In my project, I want to refresh as well as savestate of the data table (datatable saveState) while updating the status in Laravel, the status is getting updated into the database but the data table is not refreshed nor the savestate is done, I am not able to understand where I am doing the mistake, below here is the code that I am using

Route

```
Route::get('/list-category', [CategoryController::class, 'listcategory'])->name('listcategory');
```

Controller

```
public function changestatus($id){

$cat_statuss = Category::find($id);

if (!empty($cat_statuss)) {
    // dd('Record is available.');
    $cat_status = Category::where('id',$id)->first();
    $status  = $cat_status->status;
    $statuss = 'active';
    if($status=='active'){
        $statuss = 'inactive';
    }else{
        $statuss = 'active';
    }

    $cat_status->status = $statuss;

    if($cat_status->update()){
        // return redirect('/list-category')->with('status_change','Updated Successfully.');
        return response()->json(array(
            'success' => true,
            'message'=> 'Status Changed Successfully.',
            'errors' => false
    
        ), 200); 
    }else{

        return response()->json(array(
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => array('status_change_err'=>'Oops! There is an error.')
    
        ), 400);

    }
}else{
    // dd('Record is not available.');
    return response()->json(array(
        'success' => false,
        'errors' => array('status_change_err'=>'Category Not Found.')

    ), 404);
}



}
```

List Category Page

```
<td> 
<a href="category_status/{{$cate->id}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to change the status?');" class="status_button btn btn-sm btn-<?php if($cate->status=='inactive'){ echo 'danger'; }else{ echo 'success'; } ?>" data-id="{{$cate->id}}"> <?php if($cate->status=='active'){ echo 'Active'; }else{ echo 'Inactive'; } ?></a>
</td>

<script>

var table = $('#example2').DataTable( { stateSave: true } );

$(document).on('click','.status_button',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var statusid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method:"GET",
        data:{"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){

          // console.log(response);

          swal({
          title: "Added",
          text: response.message,
          type: "success"
          }, function () {

            

            
          });

          
            
        },
        error: function(response) {
          swal("Error", response.responseJSON.errors.status_change_err, "error");
        }


    });
});
    
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_savestate of the data table_"? Are you referring to the DataTables [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option, or something different? Can you [edit] your question to clarify?

Comment: @andrewjames yes DataTables stateSave

Comment: OK - then go ahead and add the [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option to your DataTable.

Comment: I saw your edits - that is not how you define initialization options for DataTables. See the example in the documentation. In your case it would be: `var table = $('#example2').DataTable( { stateSave: true } );`

Comment: @andrewjames when i am using only this nothing happens

Comment: Saying "nothing happens" is not really very helpful. Please [edit] your question. Describe the specific steps you take, the results you _expect_ to happen, and the results which _actually_ happen. Also provide any error messages (as formatted text) from the browser's console. But first, you need to correct your `stateSave` code, as described in my previous comment.

Comment: @andrewjames 'nothing happens' means data table did not get refreshed and my status button is not showing inactive as I am changing active status to inactive

Comment: You are still not applying DataTable options correctly. You apply these once, at the start of your code. Instead of `var table = $('#example2').DataTable();` use `var table = $('#example2').DataTable( { stateSave: true } );`. Look at the documentation I linked to. (Also, if you are using ajax, then why not use DataTables' built-in support for ajax? And you did not [edit] your question.)

Comment: @andrewjames okay i did that but the same results data table is not refreshing but now statesave happens but there is one another problem now when page 2 data is updated after refreshing the page by default the page 2 is shown I want the page 1 during the page refresh